# Specify Nginx ingress for both web and api

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I am trying to get https on both my web interface as my api for a domain. I tried with nginx ingress. It works fine for www.example.com, but now I need to add the api at api.example.com. I tried in the following way, but to no avail. Removing the api related sections and it works fine for the web interface, otherwise the web interface also does not work. How can I specify my ingress file such that it adds https on the api.example.com and similarly on www.example.com domains?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.example.com
        - api.example.com
      secretName: example-secret
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: web-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5000
    - host: api.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: api-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5005
```

The certmanager file is set-up as follows.

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: example-tls
spec:
  secretName: example-secret
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: example.com
  dnsNames:
    - example.com
  acme:
    config:
      - http01:
          ingressClass: nginx
        domains:
          - example.com
```

Comment: The annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url` is deprecated and was removed in version 0.22.0. Maybe this causes your issue?

Comment: That helped, but I also made a bad error of setting up the api.example.com DNS incorrectly. Got it working now.